# In a nginx configuration file, how to define a fastcgi_param that contains the "$" sign?

Tags: nginx, configuration, fastcgi, environment-variables, escaping

I'm trying to define a few environment variables for a PHP application but one of these variables contains the "$" sign. When I test the configuration file with `nginx -t`, I get an error message telling me that a variable does not exist. It seems to interpret the text after "$" as a variable name, which is of course not defined.

Maybe I did not search in the right places, but I couldn't find information about how to escape the "$" character. Is that possible and how can it be done?

Update: I tried to enclose the value between single quotes and double quotes following d3ag0s's comment but I had the same error message.

Comment: Try using quotes for your environment variable that contain special characters.

Comment: I just did (using ' and ") but unfortunately it does not change the error message.

Comment: Try setting the variable `set $myvar "$environmentvariable"` then use $myvar instead

Comment: I just tried it as well but unfortunately, the value is still being evaluated in the variable assignment.

Comment: Have you tried `\$` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it as well, but no luck :\

Answer (score 6):

According to this page, it is not possible to escape the $ sign, but they provide a workaround:

https://openresty.org/download/agentzh-nginx-tutorials-en.html#nginx-variables-escaping-dollar

```
geo $dollar {
    default "$";
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location /test {
        echo "This is a dollar sign: $dollar";
    }
}
```

Although it might not be the best solution, I have tested it and it works.

Comment: OMG this is a f--king terrible 'solution'. I have to define a variable in a file completely separate from my fastcgi_params file to get it in my fastcgi_params file? How do you even pass this off from nginx to FPM?

Comment: @tpartee good day to you too. I don't understand your comment, because you don't need to declare the variable in a separate file, I certainly did not. You can pass a variable from nginx to FPM with: `fastcgi_param VAR_NAME value;`